# advancing pointer in a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying to create a function to advance the current pointer in a linked list to the next entity in the list.  Here is my list structure;

```
    * malloc() a new list header and initialize it */
list_t *list_init(void)
{
    list_t *list = (list_t *)malloc(sizeof(list_t));
      list->first = NULL;            
          list->last = NULL; 
      list->current = NULL; 
return list;      
}
```

here is my link structure

```
    /* add an element to the end of a list */
void list_add(list_t *list, void *entity)
{
    link_t *link = (link_t *)malloc(sizeof(link_t));       
         link->entity = (link_t *)entity; 
     //link->next = (link_t *)list;  
       if(list->first != NULL){
            list->last = link;
            link->next = NULL;
            list->last->next = list->current;
            list->current = list->last;
       }        
               else { 

               list->first = link->entity;  }
}
```

and here is the function I am trying to create, where I am having problems in getting it to advance to the next entity

```
/* advance current pointer to next link */
void list_next_link(list_t *list)
{

   assert(list->current != NULL);

    list->last->next = list->current;
    list->last->next =list->current->entity;
    list->current = NULL;   

}
```

I'm unsure how I'm supposed to get it to advance to the next link;  the first entry prints fine and the rest look like they are being printed from random memory addresses before it has a segmentation fault.

Comment: What are the two lines assigning `list->last->next` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your list is designed to be a container of "entity" objects, as it appears from your add function, then there are two problems I see very quickly. First of all, the entity data type should be wholly independent of the list data type, so casting it to `link_t *` in list_add is wrong, and at best will be confusing. This may be the source of the second problem: no next pointer in your list should EVER point to an "entity" object. "next" pointers should only ever point to valid items in list created with list_add. I have not examined in detail what your list_next_link is *intended* to do, however it is almost certainly wrong to overwrite "next" pointers with the contained value in the list. Reinterpreting whatever data you have in the list item as a list pointer is bound to cause problems.

Comment: I'll rewrite it and keep that in mind.  I'm assuming the valid items to point to for next would be whole links (including their own "next" substructures) instead of just the entity?  "entity" is a void pointer in order to return a generic type, so that is why I (mistakenly) used a typecast.